# Difficult weeks calculation based on date in DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have DataFrame like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"data" : ["25.01.2020", and many more other dates...]})
df["data"] = pd.to_datetime(df["data"], format = "%d%m%Y")
```

And I have a series of special dates like below:

```
special_date = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(["16.01.2020",
                                         "27.01.2020",
                                         and many more other dates...], dayfirst=True))
```

And I need to calculate 2 more columns in this DataFrame:

col1 = number of weeks to the next special date

col2 = number of weeks after las special date

So I need results like below:

col1 = 1 because the nearest next special date after 25.01 is 27.01 so it is the same week

col2 = 2 because the nearest last special date before 25.01 is 16.01 so i is 2 weeks ago

*please be aware that I have many more dates, so code needs to work for more dates than only 2 special dates or only 1 data from df.

[image]

Comment: To make this problem simpler, you can pre-compute the nearest next/last special dates for all possible dates in your dataframe. Then, map the `data` columns using the pre-computed values.

Comment: could you propose some code ?